# Not able to populate PickerView with my string

Tags: ios, uipickerview, textfield, populate, inputview

I am using the inputView to display a pickerView when a a textfield is clicked.  I then want to populate the pickerview with the numbers 1-100. I have some code that I thought would work, but when i run the program and click on the textField, it just pops up an empty pickerview. Also need to know how to put another button on the toolbar.  I would like to have a submit button on the right side to confirm the users selection (going to change the done to cancel)  Is there something I have to do in the interface builder with the picker and buttons? because i don't actually have those in the interface builder because they are made with code...

Below are my .h and .m files.

.h----

```
@interface TestinputviewViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate> {

IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
NSMutableArray *pickerViewArray;
}
-(IBAction) textFieldDidBeginEditing;
@end
```

.m---

```
 #import "TestinputviewViewController.h"

@implementation TestinputviewViewController


-(IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing{


UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
textField.inputView = myPickerView;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.dataSource = self;
    [myPickerView release];


UIToolbar *myToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
                        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self   action:@selector(inputAccessoryViewDidFinish)];
[myToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:doneButton] animated:NO];
                        textField.inputAccessoryView =     myToolbar; 

}   



-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)myPickerView {
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *) myPickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component {
return [pickerViewArray count];
}

-(NSString *)pikerView:(UIPickerView *) myPickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

pickerViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 1; i<=20; i++) {
    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%",i];
    [pickerViewArray addObject:myString];

}
}
```

Comment: did u made the **pickerViewArray** as a subview of TextField?.

Comment: No, I'm not sure what you mean. @New Xcoder

Comment: Just put the picker array in viewdidload method and call the array in function..

Comment: I put the picker array underneath viewdidLoad.  I have posted an update to my original question with the new code.  Please look at it. I am still just getting question marks in the picker.  In my array, if i change the number in this part of code (i<=20) if i change 20 to another number it will change the number of question marks. @NewXcoder

Comment: I just figured it out!!! there was a typo in the titleForRow...I had pikerView instead of pickerView!! Thanks for the help! @NewXcoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting delegate of picker to the current object class.

use

```
`myPickerView.delegate = self;`

 `myPickerView.dataSource = self;`
```

after allocating the picker view object.

go on..

Comment: He also needs to set his datasource.

Comment: I used the code you gave me, now when the pickerview pop up it just shows question marks in it instead of numbers. Am I not coding the 'pickerviewarray right?

Comment: I know that if i had the pickerview actually displayed on the main view without a button, i would code the array under viewdidload.  But i tried that and it did nothing.